# Split records based on month difference

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to generate rows, 1 row for each month that occurs in between 2 given dates.
Consider the tables:
plcy:

```
plcy_no | plcy_strt_dt | plcy_end_dt
12345 | 10/01/2019 | 15/04/2019
24365 | 04/05/2019 | 22/07/2019
```

The requirement is for each policy, split the record into number of rows equal to the number of months that occur between the `plcy_strt_dt & plcy_end_dt`.

Hence considering the sample data (above) `plcy = 12345` has start date in `Jan 2019` and end date in `Apr 2019`. Hence that record needs to be split in 5 records which need to be generated for each of the months in between (i.e. `Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr`) and populate the start and end dates as follows.

Expected output:

```
plcy_no | plcy_strt_dt | plcy_end_dt
12345 | 10/01/2019 | 31/01/2019
12345 | 01/02/2019 | 28/02/2019
12345 | 01/03/2019 | 31/04/2019
12345 | 01/04/2019 | 15/04/2019
24365 | 04/05/2019 | 31/05/2019
24365 | 01/06/2019 | 30/06/2019
24365 | 01/07/2019 | 22/07/2019
```

Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if additional information is required.
I can use Spark-SQL only.

Thanks

Comment: Which Spark version do you use?

Comment: @Mahesh Gupta - Spark 2.4. I was trying to combine repeat(), explode() etc to but couldn't get it to work. Btw, creating temp views at each step to hold intermediate results are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> Spark2.4+ try this using spark SQL

```
scala>  var df = Seq(("12345","10-01-2019","15-04-2019"),("24365","04-05-2019","22-07-2019")).toDF("plcy_no","plcy_strt_dt","plcy_end_dt")
scala> df.registerTempTable("temp")
```

here i am using sequence function to generate the date

```
scala> sql("select *,last_day(CAST(start_date AS DATE)) end_date from (SELECT plcy_no,explode(sequence(to_date(plcy_strt_dt,'dd-MM-yyyy'), to_date(plcy_end_dt,'dd-MM-yyyy'), interval 1 month)) as start_date from temp)t").show()

+-------+----------+----------+
|plcy_no|start_date|  end_date|
+-------+----------+----------+
|  12345|2019-01-10|2019-01-31|
|  12345|2019-02-10|2019-02-28|
|  12345|2019-03-10|2019-03-31|
|  12345|2019-04-10|2019-04-30|
|  24365|2019-05-04|2019-05-31|
|  24365|2019-06-04|2019-06-30|
|  24365|2019-07-04|2019-07-31|
+-------+----------+----------+
```

hope this helps.